# Не работает подстветка кода в codemirror

Tags: html, css, codemirror

Использую библиотеку [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/)

```
<textarea id="myTextarea" name="text" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

```
<script src="/codemirror-5.26.0/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("myTextarea"), {
        lineNumbers: true, // Нумеровать каждую строчку.
        matchBrackets: true,
        mode: "text/html",
        indentUnit: 2, // Длина отступа в пробелах.
        indentWithTabs: true,
        enterMode: "keep",
        tabMode: "shift"
      });
    </script>
```

Запускается нумерация работает а вот подсветка кода не хочет, почему не понятно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `<script src="/codemirror-5.26.0/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>`, чтобы подсветка
 заработала. Это необходимо для выбора языка, в синтаксисе которого
 будет подсвечиваться код.

P.S. Файл **xml.js** находиться п адресу **/codemirror-5.26.0/mode/xml/xml.js**. Так же
 может быть выбран любой другой язык. Например:

- **CSS** ( /codemirror-5.26.0/mode/css/css.js )
- **Javascript** ( /codemirror-5.26.0/mode/javascript/javascript.js )
- **PHP** ( /codemirror-5.26.0/mode/php/php.js )

Остальные доступные языки можно посмотреть на оофициальном сайте
[codemirror.net](http://codemirror.net/mode/index.html). Как на [сайте](http://codemirror.net/demo/) так и в директории **/demo/**
представленно множество примеров использования.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/170556)

Comment: @alexolut да ну?

Comment: @D-side я не вижу ответа, я вижу вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut о ужас! Можно с тем же успехом написать "добавьте `код`, чтобы подсветка заработала". Вопрос тут лишь в формулировке.

Comment: @D-side считаете, формулировка не важна?

Comment: @alexolut я считаю, что в этом ответе, независимо от формулировки, предлагается решение. Хотя прямоту формулировки можно использовать как критерий оценки качества этого ответа, тревоги "не является ответом" на нём неуместны.

Comment: @D-side а это не тревога, это проверка из очереди. Если я ошибаюсь, и ответ действительно является ответом, автор скорее всего его отметит галочкой и плюсанет (Вы, кстати, могли бы тоже так выразить свою позицию, или даже улучшить его, чтобы исключить возможные разночтения). Таким образом, он не будет потерян для сообщества.

Comment: @alexolut Я надеюсь теперь ответ более понятный и точный.